# Parsed F# DateTime value not equal to the original DateTime value

Tags: datetime, parsing, f#, equality

Consider the following code that converts a `DateTime` to a `string`, tries to parse it using the `TryParse` method on `DateTime`, and returns an `DateTime option` indicating whether parsing the `string` was successful or not:

```ml
let dt = DateTime.Now

printfn "%A" dt

let parseDateTime (str: string) =
  match DateTime.TryParse str with
    | (true, v) -> Some v
    | _ -> None
    
let parsedDateTime =
  dt.ToString () |> parseDateTime

match parsedDateTime with
| Some v -> 
  printfn "%A" v
  assert (v = dt)
  
| _ -> ()
```

The `assert` statement fails, which I would not expect it to. `printfn` prints out the same string to the Console which further puzzles me.

If I change the `assert` statement above to `assert (v.ToString() = dt.ToString())` the `assert` passes as I would have expected when comparing the two `DateTime` values.

Is there something that I'm missing here when it comes to `DateTime` equality? I've also tested this using `int` and `Guid` (swapping out `DateTime.TryParse` for `Int32.TryParse` and `Guid.TryParse` respectively) and the `assert` passes as I would expect it to when comparing values for equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution of a `DateTime` value is a single "[tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks)", which represents one ten-millionth of a second. You also need to consider time zone differences. The default output format doesn't include this level of detail. If you want to "[round trip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values)" a `DateTime`, write it out with `ToString("o")`and then use `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` when parsing:

```ml
open System
open System.Globalization

let parseDateTime (str: string) =
  match DateTime.TryParse(str, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind) with
    | (true, v) -> Some v
    | _ -> None

let parsedDateTime =
  dt.ToString ("o") |> parseDateTime   // e.g. "2021-11-15T15:36:07.6506924-05:00"
```